# Is there "all you can race" go-karting in New York City, USA?

Tags: driving, new-york-city, amusement-parks

I know this is a bit of a long shot, but does anyone know of any "all you can race" go-karting places in New York City?

I don't care if the conditions are hellish, for example: "this offer only applies during the graveyard shift (23:00 - 07:00)".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Karts Indoor Raceway on Long Island offers [unlimited racing Tuesdays](http://karts1.com/racing-specials/) between 6pm to 10pm for $52.

If you're willing to travel a bit farther, iPlay America in Freehold, NJ, has an [iRide Plus Pass Package](http://www.iplayamerica.com/pricing-and-specials) which offers unlimited go-karting for a day for $29.95. NJ Transit buses will get you there in an hour and a half from Port Authority terminal.

Finally, Pole Position Raceway in Jersey City, NJ, has [a "Legend" membership](https://www.polepositionraceway.com/jersey-city/prices/arrive-and-drive/) which lets you race all you want for an entire *year*. It costs $4999. They do not have any other unlimited race memberships.

Comment: Is the fact that it's summer holiday in the U.S. going to invalidate unlimited racing Tuesdays?

Comment: I would not think so. Generally when I see "school holiday" I think of the days during the school year when school is closed, rather than the entire summer. But the web site isn't really explicit about that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Seems a funny distinction to me. In the UK at least if such offers are invalid during school holidays that certainly includes the Summer holiday.

Comment: @OllieFord The US is a funny place. I never quite knew _how_ funny until I was exposed to everywhere else...

Comment: Alright, so I just called Karts Indoor Raceway, and they are NOT honouring "unlimited racing Tuesdays" right now. Good find never the less.

Comment: @MurphyDanger That's ok, we both know you _really_ want to race non-stop for the next year... :)

Comment: Freehold is not "a bit farther" than Ronkonkoma, depending where in New York City one is.  They are about the same distance from Penn Station.

Comment: @phoog Good point. I just hate New Jersey.